# Error when installing ffmpeg-php

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php and am getting an error when I try to use make. I've tried to get to the bottom of it but it has me stumped. I tried finding which file has references to swscale.h but didn't have any luck. Has anyone encountered this error before?

```
root@vps [/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]# make
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile gcc  -I. -
I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-
I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-
php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -
I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/local/include/php -
I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -
I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -
I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -
I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -
I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -
I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -I/usr/local/include/php -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
-g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-
0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -
I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-
0.6.0/main -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/local/include/php -
I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -
I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -
I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -
I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -
I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -
I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -I/usr/local/include/php -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g 
-O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-
php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:46:21: error: swscale.h: No 
such file or directory
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c: In function 'zm_info_ffmpeg':
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:156: error: 'LIBSWSCALE_IDENT' 
undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:156: error: (Each undeclared 
identifier is reported only once
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:156: error: for each function 
it appears in.)
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it can't find `swscale.h`.  You should check to see if that file was included with your FFmpeg install, and, if so, that ffmpeg-php has the correct set of paths specified with `-I/path/to/includes` to find it.  If it doesn't, you can add the correct directory with something like:

```
CFLAGS=-I/path/to/ffmpeg/includes ./configure
make
```

If you can't find `swscale.h`, it could be that there's some version mismatch between FFmpeg and ffmpeg-php.  The former is pretty actively developed, and pieces that ffmpeg-php expects to find might no longer be present.  Check the docs for ffmpeg-php to see if it's tied to a particular version.

Answer (score 2):

Installing **libswscale-dev** helped me on Debian Squeeze

Comment: This solution is also applicable when building transcode on ubuntu 12.04